# Emacs: How to select word under cursor and append to file

Tags: emacs

I want the following behavior:

Append the word under cursor into a file(`~/vocabulary.txt`, for example)
Better still to bind a key for it.

Could anyone show me how to do it?
Should I put those code into `.emacs` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following function:

```
(defun my-write-to-file ()
  "Save word at point to file"
  (interactive)
  (write-region (concat (thing-at-point 'word) "\n") nil "~/vocabulary.txt" 'append))
```

When called, this function will save the word at point (the word the cursor is on or the word right before the cursor) to `~/vocabulary.txt`.
You can bind it to a key (`C-c w` in this case, but you can change it to whatever you like) like this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c w") 'my-write-to-file)
```

To use, simply put the function and the keybinding assignment in your `.emacs`.

Answer (score 1):

@Elethan wrote you a command that does just what you ask for, and bound it to a key.

It might also help to mention some general commands that you can use for this kind of thing. `M-x append-to-file` appends the region contents to a file, and `M-x write-region` prepends.

The manual is your friend for things like this. See nodes [Misc File Ops](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Misc-File-Ops.html) and [Accumulating Text](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Accumulating-Text.html).

Be aware too that for the two commands just mentioned, as the manual says about `append-to-file` (it should say it about both):

> You should use `append-to-file` only with files that are *not* being
>   visited in Emacs.  Using it on a file that you are editing in Emacs
>   would change the file behind Emacs’s back, which can lead to losing some
>   of your editing.

[Accumulating Text](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Accumulating-Text.html) also tells you about commands for adding text to a buffer, including the case of adding to a buffer for a file that you are visiting (as opposed to what the above quote warns you about for `append-to-file`).  These include commands `append-to-buffer` and `prepend-to-buffer`.